# Dask apply groupby meta changes index column dtype

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have the following minor example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'col2': [80, 80, 443, 80,80], 'col3':['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']})
```

the dtypes are:

```
df.dtypes

col1    object
col2     int64
col3    object
dtype: object
```

and grouping by:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).col3.apply(lambda series: 'yes' in series.values).reset_index().dtypes

col1    object
col2     int64
col3    object
dtype: object
```

But if I use a dask dataframe:

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
ddf.dtypes

col1    object
col2     int64
col3    object
dtype: object
```

and grouping by using meta:

```
meta = make_meta({'col3': '?'})

meta.index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []], codes=[[],[]], names=['col1', 'col2'])

ddf.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).col3.apply(lambda series: 'yes' in series.values, meta=meta).reset_index().dtypes

col1    object
col2    object
col3      bool
dtype: object
```

col2 has changed to object. Should I use in a different way the meta keword?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by passing dummy values for the level so as dask to be able to extract the necessary informations:

```
meta.index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['a'], [1]], codes=[[],[]], names=['col1', 'col2'])
```